# CMS static block not showing up

Tags: magento-1, cms-block, home

I have defined a CMS/Static block in the magento admin called: slick_slideshow, it has content and is enabled

I've updated my page.xml and added:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="slick_slideshow"></block>
```

to the default section immediately following the breadcrumbs block.

in my 1column.phtml after the breadcrumbs block I've added:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('slick_slideshow') ?>
```

Cache is currently disabled, but nothing shows up!! Ideally I need this to only show on the homepage. but it won't show up on any page right now.

What could the issue be?

Comment: You added very little code / context in your question. I'm not totally sure, but it could be that getChildHtml() requires the alias set with `as` and not the name set with `name`. But I can't look it up right now and I'm not totally sure. Are you placing it into the correct update handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="slick_slideshow">
     <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>slick_slideshow</block_id></action>
</block>
```

and then in the template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('slick_slideshow') ?>
```

All your changes should be in `local.xml` (convention).

Comment: I swear I tried it with the action tag!!